# How can I emulate a modal result from a form which has no buttons?

Tags: delphi

I have a form which will be displayed modally with only a list box on it.  I want to be able to return a modal result of mrOK on double clicking an item in the list box or a modal result of mrCancel when the user presses escape.

When there is no button on the form to assign a modal response to how do can I emulate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually very easy: just set the form's [`ModalResult`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.ModalResult) property:

> Use **ModalResult** to close the form when it is displayed modally.

> By default, **ModalResult** is mrNone. Set **ModalResult** to any nonzero value to close the form. The value assigned to **ModalResult** becomes the return value of the ShowModal function call used to display the form.

In your case,

```pascal
procedure TForm1.ListBox1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ListBox1.ItemIndex <> -1 then
    ModalResult := mrOk;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  case Key of
    VK_RETURN:
      if ListBox1.ItemIndex <> -1 then
        ModalResult := mrOk;
    VK_ESCAPE:
      ModalResult := mrCancel;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You will probably want to handle the key presses in the `OnKey...` event of the Form itself rather than the ListBox.  Just set the Form's `KeyPreview` property to True.

Comment: Since the OP wrote "a form [...] with only a list box on it", I think it is cleaner to use the actual control's event handler.